# Add items in different tables in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code :

```
return (

<div className="container">    

   <div class="col-md-12 ">

    <div class ="row">
    {
            tableList.map(table => {
              return(
                <div className="item col-md-6 col-lg-3"  key={table}>
                <div>{table}</div>
                <div className="content">
                <div className="data">

   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
      <table className="item" class="auto-index" >
        <thead >
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
          {
            buyItems.map(item => {
              return(
                <tr key={item}>
                <td></td>
                <td>{item}</td>
                <td className="text-middle">
              1
                </td>

                </tr>

              ) 
            })
          }


        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

 </div>
 <button onClick={(e)=> this.removeTable(table)} type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                  Remove
                  </button>
                </div>

                </div>


              )
            })
          }
    </div>

  </div>

 </div>
);
```

I want to add different items in different tables but items are duplicated in all table please help me guys. I am not so good at this java script so please you can help me by telling me how to post different item in the multiple table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

declare a store add put your list in it and send this store to all of your components which you want to use the list then just add items to your list and your tables all updated with new data or create master component which it has a state (your list) and pass via props to all of your components, if you have one component and multiple tables you can add the list in your state and add items with setState function and use it in your tables
Example :

```
--store
export class YourStore{
@computed get yourRows(){
return this.yourlList.map(item => {
return (
 <tr key={item}>
                <td></td>
                <td>{item}</td>
                <td className="text-middle">
              1
                </td>

                </tr>
)
})
}
@observable yourList = []

@action addItemToList(data){
this.yourList.push(data)
}

}


--component render 
<table>
<thead >
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
{this.props.yourstore.yourRows}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your expectation? The below code will render a table for each item in the buyItems

```
return (
    <div className="container">    
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <div class ="row">
                {tableList.map(table => {
                    return(
                        <div className="item col-md-6 col-lg-3"  key={table}>
                            <div>{table}</div>
                            <div className="content">
                                <div className="data">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
                                         {buyItems.map(item => (
                                            <table className="item" class="auto-index" >
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>#</th>
                                                    <th>Item</th>
                                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr key={item}>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td>{item}</td>
                                                        <td className="text-middle">1</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <button onClick={(e)=> this.removeTable(table)} type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                    Remove
                                    </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                );
```

Comment: i want to add different item in multiple table. right now when i add one item, it goes to all the table. For example you can see in the picture when i add coffee it goes in all three tables which i don't want.